# broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent

Tags: java, php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When receiving a notification in my GCM Client app im getting the following error on the log:

```
broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=package.name (has extras)
```

Which automatically leads to the device unregistering from the GCM server:

```
Unregister application package.name for user 0
```

I have already read similar questions, but their solutions dont seem to be working for me.

Here is some of the code used int he app:

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"> </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"> </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"> </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE"> </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <permission android:name="package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"> </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>


     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

     <uses-sdk
         android:minSdkVersion="11"
         android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

     <application android:name="package.name.Globales"
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

         <activity
             android:name="package.name.LoginActivity"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >

         </activity>

         <activity
             android:name="package.name.MainActivity"
             android:label="app_name"
             android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>

         <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
             android:exported="true"
             android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
             <intent-filter>

                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2md.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                 <category android:name="package.name"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>

         <service android:name="package.name.MyGcmListenerService"
             android:exported="false">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </service>

         <service android:name="package.name.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
             android:exported="false">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </service>

        <service android:name="package.name.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false"></service>


     </application>


 </manifest>
```

GCM Listener:

```
package package.name;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);


        sendNotification(message);

    }



    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(001 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

php used to send notification:

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'KEY' );
//$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
$registrationIds=array('ID');
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'message',
    'title'     => 'title',
    'subtitle'  => 'subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'ic_launcher',
    'smallIcon' => 'ic_launcher'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

The device registers just fine.
Any ideas on how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: does it happen on all device?

Comment: yes, it happens on all devices I have tested on.

Comment: I don't know if it can help solve the issue but I noticed that you have extra "-->"  character in your manifest.

Comment: forgot to delete that when posting the question. It isnt in the actual manifest. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I guess you need to post the actual (just hide the confidential info) or else no one could help you

Comment: Thats the manifest, I just had commented a permission for testing, but that didnt work either.

Comment: check that is Your onMessageReceived() method called  ? is yes please check what data is inside bundle and from

Comment: the onMessageReceived() method is not being called. It seems the notifications is discarded after the error.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50238790/2835520) the are some steps which could help you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late, but you seem to have a type in your Manifest

> action android:name="com.google.android.**c2md**.intent.RECEIVE"

should be **c2dm**

Greetings